# C++ type aliases with #define

Tags: c++, types, alias

I'm aware we can use `typedef` or `using` for making type aliases. However, what about using `#define`? For example:

```
#define integer int
```

Should I ever use this instead of `using` or `typedef`?

Comment: Macros are the worst option in C++ because they are namespace agnostic. E.g. your macro would become effective as well for any occurrence of `integer`, also where you gave it a different meaning like e.g. in `namespace My { struct MyStruct { double value; int integer() const { return (int)value; } }; }`. I once was in big trouble using the Win32API (which uses macros a lot) because the macros started to fake my C++ methods and (for the most accident) the result still compiled but had strange effects at runtime I was not able to explain...

Comment: Really the only thing I use the preprocessor for is things that aren't built into C++.  Type aliases are built into C++, so I do not use the preprocessor for them.

Answer (score 4):

> Should I ever use this instead of using or typedef?

Probably not. I do not know any case where a macro would be in any way better, but there are reasons why type aliases are objectively better. Most importantly, type aliases are enclosed by scopes.

Answer (score 2):

There is no reason to use a macro when you can not use a macro. Macros are not aware of scopes or namespaces. Macros are replaced before actual compilation takes place, hence macros are not C++ entities. Consider for example:

```
#define integer int

struct Foo
{
    int integer;
};
```

GCC emits the following error message:

```
<source>:5:5: error: multiple types in one declaration
    5 |     int integer;
      |     ^~~
<source>:1:17: error: declaration does not declare anything [-fpermissive]
    1 | #define integer int
      |                 ^~~
<source>:5:9: note: in expansion of macro 'integer'
    5 |     int integer;
      |         ^~~~~~~
```

because of the macro, the message is unnecessarily verbose. While reading I have to follow the indirection via the macro to understand what is going on.

On the other hand, this:

```
using integer = int;

struct Foo
{
    int integer;
};
```

Compiles without problems. `Foo` has a member called `integer`. This is just one case out of millions where using a macro causes confusion.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64226096/why-type-alias-is-allowed-as-name-of-variable/64226133#64226133) for what makes the difference.