# Why type alias is allowed as name of variable?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, using, type-alias

What rule makes the following code [compile without error](https://godbolt.org/z/a5cs4q):

```
using integer = int;

struct Foo
{
    int integer;
};

int main() {
    Foo f;
    int integer;
    f.integer;
}
```

`using` is of course not a simple replacement for `#define integer int`, but what makes this code apparently well-formed while `int int;` would make it ill-formed?

Comment: I don't understand why this question was closed. It's clear what is being asked for (even in the original question which was never edited), it's interesting for us recurring visitors of the language-lawyer tag, and there are two good answers to the question, one with the appropriate standard excerpts. I'm almost under the impression that the original high-rep close-voter did this in aggression after non-agreement in the close-voters own answer below, which, imo, does not give anything near a language-lawyer answer (_"Here are some quotes to get you started, ...").  I'm voting to re-open this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While it's a little surprising that one can access a name declared in an outer scope, and then later hide that name , it's just a straightforward application of the rules for scoping:

> A name declared in a block (9.3) is local to that block; it has block scope. Its potential scope begins at its
> point of declaration (6.3.2) and ends at the end of its block. [basic.scope.block]

In turn, the point of a name's declaration is:

> immediately after its complete declarator (Clause 11) and before its
> initializer (if any)... [basic.scope.pdecl]

So when you do `integer integer`, you haven't yet declared the block-scoped name `integer`, which means you can still see the global `integer`. This also means you *cannot* do `integer integer = (integer)0`.

It's easier to explain why `int int` won't compile. `int` is a keyword, so no syntactic rule which could declare it as a name would be able to; it doesn't match the rules for "what a name looks like".

> There are five kinds of tokens: identifiers, keywords, literals, operators, and other separators. [lex.token]

Because `int` is a keyword, it cannot be an identifier, which means it cannot be a name.

Answer (score 2):

The reason the code compiles is that the uses of `integer` are in different *scopes*.

```
using integer = int; // #1

struct Foo
{
    int integer;  // #2
};
```

Note that there is no relation between `integer` in `#1` and `#2`. There is no clash between these uses, and they might as well have different names.

Inside `Foo`, the symbol `integer` refers only to the variable. If you want to refer to the type alias, you can prepend `::`, like this:

```
struct Foo
{
  ::integer integer;  // ok
};
```

---

If the `using` declaration and the variables are in the *same* scope, then you get an error:

```
using integer = int; 
int integer;          // error, redefinition of symbol 
                      // as different kind of entity
```

or

```
struct Foo
{
    using integer = int; 
    int integer;         // error, redefinition of symbol 
                         // as different kind of entity
};
```

Comment: but thats just because then there would be two `Foo::integer`. Using the alias in the scope of `Foo` isnt the problem, `struct Foo { integer x; int integer;  }` is "fine". Anyhow I put the language-lawyer tag, because I was looking for quotes from the standard

Comment: @idclev463035818 Sorry, I missed that tag, I'll see what I can find. But `struct Foo { integer x; int integer;  }` is not fine at all. It changes the meaning of the symbol `integer` which is ifndr.